# Slack: Can <!date^...> send current date/time?

Tags: slack, slack-api

In Slack, when using [date formatting](https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#date-formatting), such as `<!date^1392734382^{date_num}|fallback text>`, **is it possible to send the current date/time** instead of providing a specific Unix time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This function is just for formatting. So you need to provide `timestamp`.

But most programming languages have a standard function that returns the current UTC time as UNIX epoch, which you can use.

For example in Python you would do:

```py
from time import time

timestamp = int(time())
```

Comment: Thanks. I was using <!date...> in Workflow Builder, /reminders and other native tooling so no option for driving from code.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer solved your question please consider marking it as solution by clicking on the checkmark. Thanks

Comment: You did not answer the question. The formatting lets you input a specific unix timestamp. The question was whether it was possible to make seq send in the "current time" instead of hard-coding it in the template. I.e. "{now()}" or smth

Comment: @er I did answer the question. The answer is that it is not possible.